# What is mqt_native_modules and what to do about its crashes

Tags: android, react-native, crash, segmentation-fault

I'm working with React Native (noob) and I'm getting some crashes like the following on Android:

```
libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (mqt_native_modu)
```

What is this module `mqt_native_modu`? Is it a core react native library?

I'm getting these crashes while using a third party library, which otherwise works fine on both Android and iOS, via react native. So I'm wondering: is it just a problem with React Native (in which case I have to throw up my hands and wait for a fix from Facebook) or is there some other possible approach to work around it?

Comment: did you find a fix for this?

Comment: I don't think so

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(as of RN v55) `mqt_` is a prefix for `MessageQueueThread` in RN (android).

When a native module is called from javascript code, its code runs on this thread. The callstack may help to identify the cause of SIGSEGV.

Comment: hey, can you tell me which call stack do you mean and how to check it